# Как из бинарника и dll сделать единый .exe файл?

Tags: c++, dll

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Файл hello.exe, при запуске требует dll'ки, могу закинуть их в папку, но можно ли сделать hello.exe так, чтобы он запускался и не требовал библиотек. Можно ли их склеить? Спасибо.

Comment: Надо прилинковать статическую версию dll.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не совсем корректно ставите вопрос.
"Влинковать" DLL в EXE не получится, но можно при построении приложения указать, что следует компоновать его не с динамическими, а со статическими библиотеками.

В Visual C++, например, это делается с помощью ключа `/MT` или выбора в среде в свойствах проекта - создание кода - библиотека времени выполнение - многопоточная /MT.

Answer (score 0):

Про MSVC ответили в соседнем ответе.

В MinGW это решается добавлением `-static` во флаги линковщика.